# Inno setup custom page Side banner

Tags: inno-setup

I want the side banner in all my custompages.How to achieve that.
Below is the code that i have tried but it only puts side banner in the main welcome screen.

```
[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
***WizardImageFile= "E:\Lokendra\ProjectImages\TabImage.bmp"***
SetupIconFile=E:\Lokendra\ProjectImages\TestIcon2.ico
```

Can anyone help me with the code where side banner always appear with different image.
[image]

Here the image inside the rectangle is side banner or we can say a ".bmp" image.
Now on next button click i want similar side banner on next screen as well with different image.

[image]

In the image i want side banner on the left side.Can we do that???
If so how to achieve this.
Kindly help..

Comment: You're saying you want the side banner in all your custom pages, but you've posted a screenshot of the directory selection page, which is not a custom page. So do you want to have that image in all the pages, not only the custom ones ?

Comment: And, to answer your question. Yes, you can do it, but keep in mind that you won't have much space left for the controls inside the page.

Comment: By default, only the Welcome and Finished pages have the large side banner -- all the other pages have the small image in the top right corner instead.  You can customise that image with `WizardSmallImageFile`.  As TLama said, while it's possible to add a larger image to the other pages, they're not really designed for it and you'd have to move and resize everything to accomodate it.

Comment: @TLama The image that i have posted is for description.I want to add the Side banner similar to the first image in second image as well and all the next pages on Next button click.All the images are different.How to Achieve this.Sorry for late reply

Comment: @Miral Kindly throw some lights on how achieve this.This would really be helpful for me..Please reply.

Comment: See the `CodeClasses.iss` example script, and the `TWizardForm` definition in the Support Classes Reference.  You can add additional controls and move around the existing standard controls as much as you like -- just bear in mind that the result is seldom worth the effort.

Comment: @Miral I have gone through that example but it does not have any example where we can have side banner as needed in my case..The side banner could be just applied on first page.How to implement it in other pages i did not get any example on that. :(

Comment: You will not find any prebuilt example that does that, because nobody does that.  The example shows you the concepts of setting up controls and manipulating their properties, but you'll have to use the knowledge gained from studying the example to do all the work yourself to achieve the result you want.